# How to implment a weighted percentile with MySQL

Tags: mysql, percentile, weighted

I have a large data set which includes the prices a particular product is sold at across stores. I need to found the lowest and highest price at which 80% of sales occurred. 
for example with the following data the lowest would be 1.1 and the highest 1.9:

```
price   sales
-----   -----
1       2
1.1     2
1.2     2
1.4     3
1.5     4
1.6     2
1.7     2
1.9     1
2.2     1
2.5     1
```

Can any one suggest a way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

MySQL is a database not well suited to numerical methods. [R](http://www.r-project.org/) is one of many programmable statistical suites that can source data from databases such as MySQL.

The [RODBC](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBC/index.html) package is probably a good starting point.

Comment: Although upon reflection, R may well be overkill if the problem stated is not going to get much more complex than that. I'd probably dash that off in a dozen lines of Perl or Python if needed.

Comment: Unfortunately I need to be able to do this in real time from a web application

Comment: So are you looking for an algorithm? Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: An algorithm would be a little abstract unfortunately (I am not a mathematician). I am rather after something that i can easily implement.